# how to enlist my app content into Chromecast's “WHAT'S ON" content discovery?

Tags: google-cast

latest chromecast app will provide content discovery right inside chromecast (though i haven't seen this yet, only cast-capable app icons). but according to the screenshots by google, youtube/netflix featured content will be shown on this screen to promote content instead of apps.

i don't find SDK describing related content discovery API, is there something i've missed, or it's not planned to open to 3rd party apps yet (only that google chromecast app selectively cooperated with some famous partners?)

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no mechanism for developers to publish their content in that section.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.